# Android view background color in runtime

Tags: android, colors, background

I would like to set the background color of some views in run-time (I'm getting the color from a server request).
All these views have a default color, and if I get a color from the server I would like to change it all at once.
Is there a way it will happen automatically by setting a parameter, or the only way I can do it is by calling setBackground for each of the views.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create for every view type a class that extends a corresponding class( `BkgEditText extends EditText` or `BkgView extends View`) and change the background color to the custom one in constructor. This way, the view will have the desired color when added from xml or code.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to avoid that, I would like something like setting a color variable, and all of the views will be assigned with it in the xml